# invoke Informatica PC wf from Java and read the response to resume java program

Tags: java, informatica

I need to invoke my Informatica PC wf through Java and once the WF is completed or failed give the response to java program to continue it process.

I tried command line but java is not reading response. Looking for detail suggestion on Java and as well as on informatica end

it does not matter if the informatica job is failed or succeeded it need to give the response back to Java

Comment: Please show the code for what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are many ways to do this--perhaps the easiest is to have Java touch a file somewhere that your workflow is monitoring, and then have the workflow put a result in a database or file that Java can see.

However, a more formal approach is to use web services.

See if your Informatica administrator can enable **Web Service Hub** and then read up on it in the PowerCenter documentation. I have provided the best information I can here from a document I wrote some years back.

There may be better ways of doing this, but Informatica hasn't changed much over the years, and WSH was the way to go some years back if you wanted to launch a workflow remotely from Java or any other language and monitor its progress.

Once the admin has enabled WSH, you then can navigate to a console (likely at /wsh) that shows various actions that can be performed and various objects.

Here's a quick-and-dirty go at running a workflow using web services from the WSH console:

- Open **Web Services Hub** and navigate to **Batch WebService** and **Integration WebService**
- Click the **Try-It** button (the WSDL for the Integration web service is available here as well)
- Select the **login** operation on the left side
- Fill in the **Domain**, **Repository**, **Username**, and **Password** and click **Send**
- Obtain the **Session ID** in the SOAP response
- Select the **startWorkflow** operation on the left
- Provide the **SessionId** value obtained from the login
- Provide **FolderName**, **WorkflowName**, **RequestMode**, **DomainName**, **ServiceName**
- Click **Send**

At this point you should receive a successful response.
The web service does not wait until the workflow completes.

Once you can use the web services to control workflows, you can use a Java web service framework like Axis to generate web service client classes for the generic batch-processing.
This approach is covered well in the Informatica documentation

Unfortunately it is a somewhat cumbersome process, but it works. Web services can be invoked as follows from Java:

1. Create a new Data Integration Service Locator and use that to obtain the Data Integration Interface. This is used to execute all Informatica WS calls. This is based on the service location embedded in the WSDL.
2. Log in to Informatica and obtain a session ID for the connection
3. Create a session header, holding the session ID, and place in the Data Integration Interface.
4. Create a Service Info object that identifies the Informatica Domain Name and Service Name.
5. Create an object to hold workflow, folder, run mode, and Service Info object
6. Launch workflow using startWorkflowEx in order to return the run ID
7. Build a WorkflowRequest object with all of the same workflow information in order to wait for completion
8. Call waitTillWorkflowComplete in order to block until the Informatica workflow completes

Other features are available, so you should be able to check return codes and such.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this.

```
        String cmd="C:\\Informatica\\9.6.1\\clients\\PowerCenterClient\\CommandLineUtilities\\PC\\server\\bin\\pmcmd.exe";
        final Process cmdProcess;

        cmdProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{cmd,""});
        OutputStream out = cmdProcess.getOutputStream();
        out.write("connect  -sv IS_NAME -d DOMAIN_NAME -u USER -p PWD".getBytes());
        out.close;
```